# Right to your own photo at the opticians

Tags: united-kingdom, property

At the opticians, such as [Boots](https://www.boots.com/opticians),
they use photographic technology to capture an image of your eye. Given that the image in reality is my property as it's my eye they're taking a photo of - can I request access to the photo but also not permit any distribution of it, i.e. can I ask them to send me the photo and they having to delete it right after?

Comment: "Given that the image in reality is my property as it's my eye they're taking a photo of": why would that be the case?  And if it were the case, who owns an image of two or more people?

Comment: If "in reality is my property as it's my..." were true, every professional portrait photographer (such as school pictures) would be working for free...

Comment: @RonBeyer You pay them for the service of taking the picture for you.

Comment: @Barmar At least in the schools I've had kids in (WI and VA), that's not how it works. The photography company photographs all the students (unless you specifically decline), then they send you a "proof packet" for you to choose from. If you owned the pictures because the subject was your child, you would be able to say "well that's my kid, give them to me free". Similar things happen with other portraits, you pay separately for the photographer's time, then purchase packages of pictures... They also clearly state the copyright is held by the photographer.

Comment: @RonBeyer In the case of the school photo, it could be the school that owns them, not the individual students, because they hired the photographer. But if the contract specifically states that the photographer keeps the copyright, that's possible.

Comment: @Barmar in US law, a contractor owns copyright by default, so the photographer would own the copyright unless the contract specifically states that the school owns the copyright, unless the contractor is a school employee whose job description includes making student portraits.  In my experience, the photographer is not a school employee.  The definition of "work made for hire" may be found at https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/101

Comment: I doubt it makes very much difference who owns the copyright to school portraits.  Assuming the student owns the copyright, the copyright owner does not have the right to demand the original or prints.  The copyright owner can prohibit the distribution of the images to others, but the photographer was not going to do that anyway!? Who besides me is going to pay for pictures of my kids?

Comment: @emory True for school portraits. Issues have occurred with actresses/models doing nude shots when they're starting out. The photographer owns the copyright and is able to shop them around as they wish (this can be lucrative if the subject becomes famous). Although I think California has a "right to publicity" law that mitigates this in some cases.

Comment: Does the UK not have any medical privacy laws like the US's HIPAA?

Answer (score 22):

Copyright in a photo belongs to the photographer, not to the subject. A picture of S (the subject) is not S's property in any sense, unless the photographer has given or sold it to S.

If the photo was linked to information about S, it might be personal Data under the GDPR (or UK-GDPR) if so, S could request erasure, but various exceptions might apply. But even then S would not aquire the right to distribute or copy the image, or any of the other parts of copyright.

Comment: Is a photograph taken for medical purposes really an "artistic work" that's possible to copyright? Does the same apply to medical X-rays, MRI, and CT? Also, could it be considered a work for hire, because the patient requested/paid for it?

Comment: I do not think it is required that the "photo was linked to information about S" for GDPR to apply.  A photograph of the retina (or iris, but that is less likely to be taken by an optician) is quite enough to identify an individual, and has been proposed as a form of identity verification.

Comment: @Barmar A photograph does not need to be an "artistic work" to be copyrightable; it just needs to be a "creative work", and the act of creating a photograph meets that description regardless of context or the photographer's intent.

Comment: @kaya3 What's the legal distinction between "artistic" and "creative"?

Comment: @Barmar I will have to look into the copyright status of mdical images. But it can't be a work-for-hire. Under US law that requires a written agreement explicitly making the work such, **and** then the work must fit into one of nine specified and rather narrow categories. Neither would fit this case. The words the law uses is "original work of authorship", court cases use both ":original" and "creative" and define the later as meaning that skill and judgement were used to create something new. However a very small amount of creativity is enough. The word "artistic" is not normally used.

Comment: @Barmar The distinction is that copyright applies to a "creative work" whereas the term "artistic work" does not (as far as I know) have a legal meaning in this context; and the everyday meaning of "artistic" is mostly unrelated to whether a work is copyrightable.

Comment: @Barmar a creative work is not necessarily artistic.  Photographic medical records, as in the question, serve as a good example: the photographer creates the image despite (probably) having no artistic intent.  (Similarly, a prose description of a patient's appearance is a "literary work" under copyright law while likely having no artistic merit.)  Patients probably have a right to obtain copies of these creations because they are medical records, but they do not own the copyright.

Comment: An example of a totally inartistic but creative work: There's a car crash. To analyze the situation, Alice goes out and photographs the situation from 10 positions of her choice. The choice of the positions and angles is the only creative input she does, but that is enough to grant her a copyright.

Comment: Can't a photo also be a derivative work, if the subject is an artistic work in its own right? For example under french jurisdiction the issue with regards to the Eiffel Tower lighting: https://www.toureiffel.paris/en/news/history-and-culture/everything-you-need-know-about-eiffel-tower-night

Comment: @user1937198  A photo of an artistic or creative work is often a derivative work, even if it adds additional original aspects sufficient to have a separate copyright. Such a derivative work requires permission from the copyright holder if the base work is still in copyright, unless an exception to copyright such as fair use or fair dealing applies.

Comment: @Barmar The source code for Microsoft Word is copyrighted. I doubt anyone would say it is “artistic”. Copyright law does not only protect art. It protects any intellectual/informational output that is original and fixed.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I guess it's the "originality" that I don't see in medical imaging. How is it different from the results of a blood test? They're just recording facts about the patient's body. Is there originality in the X-ray technician deciding how to position the patient's body to get the desired shot for the doctor?

Comment: @Barmar Originality is often litigated in the courts, since what is original versus derivative, etc. is not nearly as objectively clear as what is fixed. But rather than getting bogged down with my semi-clumsy summary, I suggest taking from my comment that copyright law is not about artistry.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I agree that was a poorly chosen word. "Creativity" is better. And medical imaging seems to have the same level of creativity as drawing blood.

Answer (score 5):

David Siegel's answer is the correct one from a legal point of view, but I wanted to add some additional information:

The software that their machine uses is likely to store the image in a specialist format.  GDPR requires portability of data.  This means that if you request the image then they are required to give it to you in a format which can be imported by a different optician to use it for similar medical purposes.  I do not think it means that they would have to convert it to a general purpose image format that you could use (for example) to print it out and put it on the wall.  They are not set up for this and will not know how to do it, even though it is technically possible.

As an example, I once asked at the dentist for a copy of my x-ray, because I was at an out-of-hours place.  The dentist promised he would send the image to my usual dentist.  He didn't have a clue how to export the file from their system, but he also let me take a photograph of the x-ray on his computer screen using my phone.

When I got to my normal dentist he said he had not received information from the other place and so I would have to have another x-ray.  I showed him the picture on my phone and he was happy that it was good enough to see what he needed to, so in this way I saved myself from an unnecessary dose of radiation.

I don't think I had the right insist on taking a photo of the x-ray, because they are allowed to take up 30 days to respond to GDPR requests, but in this case they were willing to do the simplest thing, which served my purpose.

Comment: "Under this right, you can ask a data controller to transmit your data to another data controller, *if such transmission is technically feasible*."

https://www.dataprotection.ie/en/individuals/know-your-rights/right-data-portability-article-20-gdpr#:~:text=In%20some%20circumstances%2C%20you%20may,of%20your%20choosing%20without%20hindrance.

Comment: In these examples I suspect a direct transfer from one optician or dentist to another optician or dentist is certainly technically feasible, but that doesn't mean that the individual you deal with will know how to do it!

Comment: Just a data point, my optician has always been happy to send me my retinal scans in a normal image format (I suspect JPEG).  In my case it was because I wanted to experiment with image registration algorithms to see if they could track my "issue" (just for amusement).